# Python 2.7 with Django: sqlite doesn't work

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to follow this tutorial for a basic site with Django:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/intro/tutorial01/

But, when I try to create a database schema with:

```
python manage.py sql polls
```

Python doesn't create the schema and I get some the following outputs:

```
sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

My manage.py configurations:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
        'NAME': 'E:\estudos\projetos\hangover\site\newsite\', # Or path to database file if using sqlite3.
        'USER': '',                      # Not used with sqlite3.
        'PASSWORD': '',                  # Not used with sqlite3.
        'HOST': '',                      # Set to empty string for localhost. Not used with sqlite3.
        'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default. Not used with sqlite3.
    }
}
```

And for the polls app

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'polls',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)
```

Comment: "If you’re using SQLite, the database will be a **file** on your computer"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your `NAME` string with `r'E:\estudos\projetos\hangover\site\newsite\db.sqlite'`, or similar.

There are two problems here. One is that Python uses backslashes to mean escape characters in strings, so the `\newsite` actually means a newline and then "ewsite"; the `r` tells it not to do that. The other is that you're giving a path to a directory, not a file.

Comment: I believe the recommendation is to use forward slashes, `/`, even on Windows.

Comment: That probably works too; I'm not a Windows user and wouldn't know. :)